# Is it a vulnerability to use req.params directly in an Express.js route without validation?

Tags: node.js, express, security

As the title says: Is it a vulnerability to use the `req.params.id` (in my example) directly in a callback function of the route?

If so what should be the right way to do it?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use('/:id',(req, res)=>{
  // do something with id req.params.id
  // like writing it to an DB
  res.send(req.params.id);
})
app.listen(3000,()=>{
  console.log('listening on http://localhost:3000/:id');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's vulnerable to use params directly without validation, your system can be hijacked with SQL injection attack.

For example, let's say you are getting user information from the database and your query looks like following,

`SELECT id, name, password from Users WHERE id = 1`

You are expecting id as per the format stored in the DB but let's say the malformed request contains id as '1 || True ' so eventually, your query get formed as follows

`SELECT id, name, password from Users WHERE id = 1 || True`

As this query will return list of all user's from the database and your code will fail, so it's better to validate every user request before starting a processing.

https://www.incapsula.com/web-application-security/sql-injection.html

Comment: I feel the answer is correct as without validation it may lead your system vulnerable for SQL injection attack. @fabianmoronzirfas What do you think on this?

Comment: I actually don't know why you got downvoted. I was asking this questions to get some clarification on that issue. I was wondering if there is already some validation happening in Express.js

Comment: Express does do any validation, it's your responsibility. You could use express-joi middleware if you want this to be handled by middleware.

Comment: Express does not provide any extra validation unless you explicitly ask for it, please check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471369/express-router-param-validation

Comment: Thanks. This package looks like it has better maintenance https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator I vote you up again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182358/discussion-between-fabianmoronzirfas-and-sanket).

Comment: The problem is.. how will space and special character get translated when you are passing it as part of a URL. I doubt that the space will get decoded on serverside when it is injected into the query. It iwll definitely cause the query to crash, but is it a security vulnerabilityt?